# 20.04 How can I edit file "Type" for files so they sort separately from 'similar' files in Files/Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, files, file-type

I have investigated similar questions, but they do not address what I want to do.

In 20.04, when I look at a folder with column "Type" enabled, I see for example, .pdf and .db files both listed as "Document" and .avs and .txt files both labeled as "Text". (I am aware of the existence of the 'Detailed Type' column, but my question applies similarly to it.)

I had assumed the answer lay in a config file within /etc, but the following command failed to identify one (for an example in the 'Detailed Type' case):

% sudo find /etc -type f -exec grep "PDF document" {} \; # not found; ditto "AVI video"

I have also looked at editing /etc/mime-types, but I want to see something more user-friendly than a mime-type format.

Q. How do I edit the 'Type' [or 'Detailed Type'] of certain files to ensure they will sort separately from other Types?

In simplest form, how do I add a new 'Type', say "Dokument", to existing types?

Comment: It looks like this may be compiled into /usr/bin/nautilus:<br>% sudo grep "Detailed Type" /usr/bin/nautilus